# Set a callback function to a new window in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, callback, new-window

Is there an easy way to set a "callback" function to a new window that is opened in javascript? I'd like to run a function of the parent from the new window, but I want the parent to be able to set the name of this particular function (so it shouldn't be hardcoded in the new windows page).

For example in the parent I have:

```
function DoSomething { alert('Something'); }
...
<input type="button" onClick="OpenNewWindow(linktonewwindow,DoSomething);" />
```

And in the child window I want to:

```
<input type="button" onClick="RunCallbackFunction();" />
```

The question is how to create this `OpenNewWindow` and `RunCallbackFunction` functions. I though about sending the function's name as a query parameter to the new window (where the server side script generates the appropriate function calls in the generated child's HTML), which works, but I was thinking whether there is another, or better way to accomplish this, maybe something that doesn't even require server side tinkering.

Pure javascript, server side solutions and jQuery (or other frameworks) are all welcomed.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

**Updated for comments:**  If you're opening your window via [`window.open()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp) then in your child page you can set a function in the child to just be a reference pointing to a parent function, so have this in the child page:

```
var RunCallbackFunction = function() { }; //reference holder only
```

Then in your parent (opener), set that function when that child window loads, like this:

```
//random function you want to call
function myFunc() { alert("I'm a function in the parent window"); }

//to actually open the window..
var win = window.open("window.html");
win.onload = function() { win.RunCallbackFunction = myFunc; };
```

This assigns the function in your parent to now be the target of that child...and you can point each child to a different function if you wish, they're all independent.

Comment: I don't want to hard code the function's name in the child window. That was a requirement. The parent window might have multiple places where it opens the same child window but with different callback functions.

Comment: @SztupY - Then just change the code around to do the same reference in the child window, one moment I'll adjust the answer.

Comment: But if the parent object opens multiple window how would each one know which one function to call? They will all call the latest function that is set.

Comment: @SztupY - Check the updated answer, should be what you're after :)

Comment: How do I make this work with an onClick on a button instead of using the onload method?

Comment: the win.onload is what I needed, obvious really, thanks

Comment: Can't get this working. Using `window.postMessage()` instead.

Comment: FYI: I have a similar requirement and I tested this approach on IE11 and it doesn't work. So I used the answer from this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3030859/detecting-the-onload-event-of-a-window-opened-with-window-open/3030893#3030893) on SO.

Comment: It worked for me when I did `win.addEventListener('load', myFunc)` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3030859/detecting-the-onload-event-of-a-window-opened-with-window-open

Answer (score 0):

sorry to up an old question but I needed to do something similar and felt the need to share a solution I'm happy with.

Parent:

```js
window.open('CHILD_URL', 'CHILD_NAME');
window.addEventListener('message', (event) => {
  if (event.origin !== 'CHILD_URL') return;
  console.log(event.data);
});
```

Child:

```
  window.opener.postMessage(data, document.referrer);
  window.close();
```

Source (with some security warnings and detailed doc):
https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Window/open

Answer (score -5):

```
var newWindow = window.open(window.location.origin);

newWindow.onload = function() {
    $(newWindow.document.body).addClass('new-window-body-class');
};
```

Comment: I don't quite see how this answers the question, or even aids it.