# What browsers support the window.postMessage call now?

Tags: javascript, cross-browser

What are all the browsers that support the `window.postMessage` call now? I am looking for browsers that support it natively, not through an iFrame hack.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

[Can I use cross-document messaging](http://caniuse.com/#feat=x-doc-messaging)

FF3+, IE8+, Chrome, Safari(5?), Opera10+

Comment: Note that IE8/9 only support strings for the data argument, whereas all other browsers support objects.

Comment: @Brando: You comment just saved my day.  I thought I would be hours trying to figure out why IE wasn't working; but lo, I am sending an object.

Comment: old post but you can send json (sting) and use eval to decode object

Comment: @ElSinus I'd avoid eval. I'd recommend using a combination of JSON.stringify and JSON.parse

Answer (score 11):

IE8 does not allow postMessage across windows/tabs

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2009/09/16/bugs-in-ie8-support-for-html5-postmessage-sessionstorage-and-localstorage.aspx

for more info check here

http://www.openajax.org/member/wiki/Browser_Variation_of_the_Hub_Reference_Implementation_%28Illustrative%29

Comment: Nice for pointing that out! I didn't even know it works across windowws/tabs in other browsers >_>

Comment: any idea if IE9 support postMessage across windows/tabs?

Comment: The postMessage() API now has asynchronous behavior for IE9 mode pages.  This article http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2009/09/16/bugs-in-ie8-support-for-html5-postmessage-sessionstorage-and-localstorage.aspx  explains the problems still arising in IE9 not sure if it has been corrected yet though.

Answer (score 7):

postMessage is supported in IE8+ HOWEVER

- Remember that IE9 and below require data to be passed in string form and not as an object.
- IE doesn't like you to call `postMessage` as soon as page loads (I'm assuming this has to do with the iframe you are posting to needing time to load).
  Use a `setTimeout` to wait one or two seconds before calling `postMessage`.
  It took me hours to figure this out and IE wasn't giving me any error message, it was just silently doing nothing until I added the setTimeout.

If you want to start with a demo which actually does work in IE, check out [this nifty tutorial by Ilya Kantor](http://javascript.info/tutorial/cross-window-messaging-with-postmessage)

Answer (score 2):

For what it's worth recently I ran into some odd webkit browser/versions out in the wild that did NOT support postMessage. I was using IE(8) detection as my means for seeking an alternative. Instead, I probably should have just done some something like this:

```
if(window.postMessage){
    console.log('Supports post message');
}
```

Or likely a bit cleaner:

```
var pm_is_supported = typeof(window.postMessage) == 'function';
```

Comment: Thanks, this is good stuff. It's not an answer to the question though and should be a comment.

Comment: Your cleaner solution does not work in IE8. In IE8 window.postMessage comes back as an object

Comment: I would stick with: return !!window.postMessage;

Answer (score 2):

All latest browsers supports that e.g. IE 11, Edge, Firefox 57+, Dafari 11+, iOS Safari 10.2+, Opera mini, Chrome for android, UC Browser etc. 
https://caniuse.com/#search=document%20messaging