# Javascript call function from an external domain iframe

Tags: javascript, cross-domain

Page A and page B are on different domains.

A is iframed on page B.

I need to call a function which is on page B from page A.

Is this possible without something like [porthole](http://ternarylabs.github.com/porthole/)?

Basically what I'm trying to do is a simple push notification (A notifies B), don't need to transfer any content.

Comment: Do you have control over both domains?

Comment: Well sort of. I have full control of A, and I can convince owner of B to put a function/script on his page.

Comment: Well, you might be able to use this: [window.postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.postMessage). (Note: it's a rather new API)

Comment: Which browsers will it not work with?

Comment: Mostly IE7 and below. It works with FF3+, IE8+, Chrome, Safari 5, Opera 10+ (see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6036418/what-browsers-support-the-window-postmessage-call-now))

Answer (score 1):

There is an HTML5 way to do this with [cross window messaging](http://ejohn.org/blog/cross-window-messaging/).

There are [various work-arounds](http://softwareas.com/cross-domain-communication-with-iframes) when HTML5 isn't available that can be used even between different origins.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid using that specific library you could use the concept it's based off of and roll your own. Here's a pretty in depth article that describes the technique without the use of a library: http://softwareas.com/cross-domain-communication-with-iframes.

Answer (score 0):

Put A and B with the same domain, different subdomain is fine. Then in the iframe A, you can call parent.function_name (parameter1, parameter 2). If you need to call that function very often, you may want to do this :

```
function p(data, div_id){parent.p(data, div_id);}
```

then in iframe A, you can just call p(data, div_id), which will actually call page B's function. I have used this a lot of comet streaming. If you are interested, you may read this, which basically use iframe to communicate with data:

http://www.shanison.com/2010/05/10/stop-the-browser-“throbber-of-doom”-while-loading-comet-forever-iframe/

Comment: subdomain solution is not an option.

Comment: Is there any reason not to just do "var p = parent.p;"?