# Communicating with iFrame contents

Tags: javascript, jquery

There is an iFrame that contains a whole document `(<html> to </html>)`. This document contains some `script` tags too. My question is, can we call the functions of the scripts which are present in the iFrame?

Comment: and is the iframe source on the same domain?

Comment: I don't know about you but [how did you miss these from the search?](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=iframe+communication)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `iframe` navigates the same domain then you can use something like this:

```
var result = document.getElementById("frame").contentWindow.func(args);
console.log(result);
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/Mnt3e/

Answer (score 0):

You can access the iframe's content via the contentDocument property, but only if it belongs to the same domain.

Comment: In that case you'll want the `contentWindow` property in order to call the functions of the inner iframe. `theIframeNode.contentWindow.foobar()` should hopefully call the global `foobar` function inside the iframe.

Answer (score 0):

If the frame is from different domain, and have the control over the source code,
you can use [`postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.postMessage) to communicate between the frames / document.

For browser support there is some information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6036418/what-browsers-support-the-window-postmessage-call-now) and we do have a [jquery plugin](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-postmessage-plugin/) with fallbacks for the browsers which do not support `postMessage`.