# How to execute javascript / jquery on a newly opened popup screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So basically I have jquery code on a page where:

1. Open a new popup window
2. Display rails view page
3. Manipulate items on a newly opened page

Don't know what sort of solutions are there, however I thought it should be really easy.

That's the code:

```
// open a popup window for example /fault_books/3
popup = window.open("/fault_books/" + <%= @fault_book.id %> , "popup");

// trying to get the scope of the element
var module = $(".module-logo", popup.document.body)

// manipulating the element
$(module).hide();
```

Comment: Or may be there is a way to add javascript to a created popup?

Comment: Did you try: `module = popup.$("body")`?

Comment: Or try : `module = $(".module-logo", popup.document.documentElement.outerHTML);`

Comment: What does happen when that code executes? Note: "nothing" is not a suitable answer; it's at best incomplete and at worst an outright lie. Have you checked your browser's console/developer tools for errors?

Comment: Gives me on `console.log(popup.document.documentElement.outerHTML);` Debugging gives me: <html><head></head><body></body></html>

Comment: You must wait for the popup content to be loaded before executing your script. Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/3030893/1236044

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure it will be cross-browser, but you may try something like :

```
var popup = window.open("/fault_books/" + <%= @fault_book.id %> , "popup");
$(popup.document).ready(function(){
  var module = $(".module-logo", $(popup.document))
  // manipulating the element
  $(module).hide();
});
```

Comment: it doesn't solve the problem, but it was close...

I just didn't realise that Rails provide multiple layouts for a single set of views... well my problem was solved

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just put your javascript code to the generated response from `"/fault_books/" + <%= @fault_book.id %>"`

In that case, just do it as normal:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var module = $(".module-logo")

    // manipulating the element
    $(module).hide();
});
```

And don't need to do anything when opening a new window, just call:

```
popup = window.open("/fault_books/" + <%= @fault_book.id %> , "popup");
```

This solution is simple and easier to maintain as scripts are self-contained. Scripts on a page do jobs only for the containing page. Let's say, if you have another page opening the same url `window.open("/fault_books/" + <%= @fault_book.id %> , "popup");`. You don't have to duplicate code.