# IE: execute jQuery plugin in popup window when document ready

Tags: jquery, popup, internet-explorer-9, document-ready

I am making use of the jOrgChart plugin and want to show a chart in a fullsize popup window. For that i am first making a popup window and then adding my chart content. The parent page has the following code:

```
popup = window.open("", "popup", params);
doc = popup.document;
doc.write("<!doctype html><html><body><ul id='popuporg'></ul><div id='chartContainer'></div></body></html>");


$(popup).ready(function(){
   $("#popuporg",popup.document).jOrgChart({
         chartElement : $('#chartContainer',popup.document),
         dragAndDrop  : false, 
         depth : -1 
    });
});
```

Once the popup with its content is ready the plugin gets executed on the relevant container. Everything is working fine in Chrome and FF but IE9 is giving me following error:

SCRIPT70: Persmission denied. 
jquery-1.7.min.js, Line 4 Char 3321

Thats the error i get, but i guess it also has something to do with the fact that IE does not wait for the popup content to be ready and executes the plugin. Any idea?

Comment: @jbl can you have a look into it wrt to your answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17043887/how-to-execute-javascript-jquery-on-a-newly-opened-popup-screen

Comment: @erik-schierboom can you have a look into it wrt to your answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17043887/how-to-execute-javascript-jquery-on-a-newly-opened-popup-screen