# window.open callback event

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to listen to the `window.open` event.
I have a function in which I export to excel as

```
window.open('URL','_self');
```

It is working fine but what I need to achieve is while exporting of data I need to show one loader and after compilation of `window.open` ,I need to remove that loader. But I am unable to catch that `window.open` callback event.

Can anyone please help me on this.

I tried `addEventListener`,load and `onload` of window events nothing worked.

```
function windowClose() {
    window.location.reload();
    alert("fdg");
}
var  popup= window.open('URL'_self' );  
popup.onload = windowClose;
```

Comment: Is the url you are opening of the [same domain](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3032004/4297364) as the page you are opening it from?

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: Hi,That URL is nothing but backend service call to download the jquery Datatable data as excel.

Answer (score 0):

Accessing a data from other window is not a good practice.

So answer to your question is **You cannot** and ***you should not***.

Well technically you cannot access data if it is from another host but to me you should not do that for same domain too, because some browsers may don't allow this with same domain. And this will depend on the security configuration of your server too.