# Print child window after images are loaded in Safari

Tags: javascript, html, printing, safari, dom-events

I have a print button which opens a new window with the content to be printed and after loading the included pictures (img-tag with src-attribute) calls `window.print`.

```js
var newWindow = window.open('', 'MyTitle');
newWindow.document.open();
newWindow.document.write(myPrintContent)
newWindow.onload = function() {
    newWindow.print();
}
newWindow.document.close(); // necessary for IE >= 10
newWindow.focus(); // necessary for IE >= 10
```

This works fine in every tested browser (Chrome, FF, IE) except Safari where the onload is triggered before the images are loaded (The DOM content is displayed correctly.).

> The load event fires at the end of the document loading process. At
> this point, all of the objects in the document are in the DOM, and all
> the images, scripts, links and sub-frames have finished loading.

I tried to use onpageload but I get the same effect.

Is there a way to wait for all images to be loaded in Safari?

Comment: I am waiting for multiple pictures within the dom, so i need a global document event (in my opinion?)

Comment: There isn't a "global" event. Instead you could count of all the images, and on each image load add one to another counter. When the counter matches the number of images, then invoke print.

Comment: I thought this is the event that is supposed to work like i expected it?

Comment: You'd think so, but does it work?

Comment: This point is on your site Sir ;)

Comment: Ah. You are right, but as you're loading an empty page (when `.open` is invoked) the `onload` event fires immediately.

Comment: That means document.write works async? I dont think so. But i will handle this issue now with base64 encoded pictures in the dom so no image load is required. Simple but less elegant...

Comment: _"document.write works async"_ that's not what I implied. Although the `onload` event doesn't even run in my example http://jsbin.com/xibeyigeqi/edit?js,output

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3030859/detecting-the-onload-event-of-a-window-opened-with-window-open