# How to write into existing HTML window with JQuery from another window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asynchronous

When I add another window using `var w = window.open("", "_blank");` , it shows as URL about:blank and I can write to its body with no problem. but at the end, looking at the sources it only has  and there is nothing to work with.

If instead I use existing HTML file,var `w = window.open("{some path}/Empy.html", "_blank");` All the `$(w.document.body).append(...` commands write somewhere else not inside the opened file.
Is there a promise I can use, to start writing to it only after the existing file finished rendering?

Answer (score 0):

this will work in IE to, extended from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3030859/detecting-the-onload-event-of-a-window-opened-with-window-open#answer-3030893)

```
function openindex(){ 
    OpenWindow = window.open("http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/article.php/3471221", "_blank");

    myFunction = function(){

        alert("hi")

        window.document.write("<TITLE>Title Goes Here</TITLE>")
        window.document.write("<BODY BGCOLOR=pink>")
        window.document.write("<h1>Hello!</h1>")
        window.document.write("This text will appear in the window!")
        window.document.write("</BODY>")
        window.document.write("</HTML>")
        window.document.close()

    }

    OpenWindow[OpenWindow.addEventListener ? 'addEventListener' : 'attachEvent'](
      (OpenWindow.attachEvent ? 'on' : '') + 'load', myFunction, false
    );

}
```

in my example i overwrite the entire page since i dont know if it has jQuery nor i tried to target specific element, but that is the way to go.

p.s. the url is just random

Comment: It only opened http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/article.php/3471221. none of the code in the function do anything

Comment: Does the page gets changed to something pink and simple?

Comment: No. Just the content of the page. I resolved my issue by saving the new HTML in a SharePoint library and then opening from there.

Comment: perhaps this will help you http://bresleveloper.blogspot.co.il/2012/05/jquery-modal-dialog-with-aspx-page.html