# JavaScript: Open new tab and detect URL change

Tags: javascript

I am trying to open a new window with a URL for oAuth, however I cannot add any event listener.

```
const wind = window.open(msg.data.url);
console.log(wind);
wind.onload = function () {
    wind.onpopstate = function (e) {
        console.log('pop', e);
    };
};
```

It just does nothing. However it turned out that `window.open()` has given me a not full window object. And that is all what I have got. How do I add event listener for that?

[image: 1]

Comment: If the url changes domain you are sort of out of luck. Cross domain limits what you can do with the window

Comment: I'm out of any event in opened window by some reason.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detecting the onload event of a window opened with window.open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3030859/detecting-the-onload-event-of-a-window-opened-with-window-open)

Comment: may be this will help please check it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3522090/event-when-window-location-href-changes

Comment: There is no event on Window object.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open#Return_value) regarding the `window.open()` function:

> The returned Window reference can be used to access properties and
>   methods of the new window as long as it complies with Same-origin
>   policy security requirements.

That means if you call `window.open("/questions")` in a terminal on this webpage, you get a full window object, but if you call `window.open("https://google.com")`, it returns only a simplified object on which you will not be able to add event listeners. This is to prevent [cross-origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy#Cross-origin_script_API_access) attacks. You may, however, transfer data to the new window object via `Window.postMessage()`, if the new window is listening for that type of event. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) for more information on that.

Comment: But what happens when the window is redirected to my origin? I'm trying to open page with OAuth which redirects back to my page then. But I can't do it in main window due to work with Angular and websocket connection established.

Comment: _“But what happens when the window is redirected to my origin?”_ - well, then you are in control of the contents inside the popup window again - so you could for example echo JS code, that performs certain functionality … If you only need to close the window, that might work directly; the reference to the opener is probably lost due to the cross-domain redirect though. In that case, you might need to communicate with the parent window using postMessage, to trigger what else needs doing from there.