# How to detect a URL change on a opened tab

Tags: javascript, tabs

I have to open a new tab in javascript and I would like to be noticed (on the main tab, the first one), if the user close the tab or if the user change the url. I know that if the second tab is on an other domain, you cannot access to the location attributes and I understand. But is there any way to detect if the user changes the URL of the child tab ? A kind of bit or flag giving me this information ?

In advance, thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54421760/javascript-open-new-tab-and-detect-url-change

Answer (score 0):

Changing the URL will result in a reload of the page, so you should detect when a page is reloaded, hence: [Check if page gets reloaded or refreshed in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004978/check-if-page-gets-reloaded-or-refreshed-in-javascript)