# Opening new tab using window.open(), but URL redirects to another page and losing handle

Tags: javascript, asp.net, function, redirect, new-window

I am using the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var win;
    win = window.open();
    win.location.href = "somepage";
    win.onload = function () {
        alert(win.location.href);
    };
</script>
```

*somepage* redirects to another page, which seems to be creating an unload event. The unload event never gets triggered, but if I change win.onload to win.onunload, it shows the href of the page of tab as soon as it loads, about:blank, and tries to direct to the href for somepage. I'm trying to get the href of the page it redirects to, before closing the page.

Comment: This thread might answer your question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3030859/detecting-the-onload-event-of-a-window-opened-with-window-open