# Makes window.print wait until the window is load

Tags: javascript, html

I need to print a page created dinamically with JavaScript and Html. My problem is that sometimes it shows a blank page. I think that it is because the "window" isn't loaded yet. How can printing wait until the window is loaded?

I tried to add the method `wait()` but the problem is the same.
This is the method for printing page:

```
function printpage(){ 
    var panel;

    panel =document.getElementById("cajaticket").innerHTML;
    var mywindow = window.open('', 'Print');
    mywindow.document.write('<html><head><link rel="stylesheet" href="css/extras/ticket.css"></head><body>');
    mywindow.document.write(panel);
    mywindow.document.write('</body></html>');
    mywindow.document.close();
    mywindow.focus();
    mywindow.print();
    mywindow.close();
    panel=null;
}
```

It should always print the window,but currently, it only works sometimes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detecting the onload event of a window opened with window.open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3030859/detecting-the-onload-event-of-a-window-opened-with-window-open)

Comment: Hi @Ivar. Duplicate? Do you refer that I could have the same page open two times?

Comment: No, I mean that the question you ask here likely already is answered in the link I posted.

Comment: ahh sorry. Thanks @Ivar :) But this is for a PopUp,no? Is the same?

Comment: Both your and their question are about the `window.open`. I'd say give it a try. Specifically [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3030893/479156).

Comment: I will try, If it solve my problem I will delete it post like a duplicate. thanks @Ivar :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need jQuery to help you with this, try this:

```
$($(window).on('load', function() {
        printpage();
    });
);
function printpage(){ 
    var panel;

    panel =document.getElementById("cajaticket").innerHTML;
    var mywindow = window.open('', 'Print');
    mywindow.document.write('<html><head><link rel="stylesheet" href="css/extras/ticket.css"></head><body>');
    mywindow.document.write(panel);
    mywindow.document.write('</body></html>');
    mywindow.focus();
    mywindow.print();
    mywindow.close();
    panel=null;
}
```

This will ensure that the `DOM` is loaded, ready and rendered before printing.

**UPDATE**: Using

```
$(mywindow).on('load', function() { 
    // manipulate mywindow here
});
```

would have been great but the documentation doesn't say explicitly that this is supported:

> The **load** event is sent to an element when it and all sub-elements have been **completely loaded**. This event can be sent to any element associated with a **URL**: images, scripts, frames, iframes, and the `window` object.

see the complete documentation [here](https://api.jquery.com/load-event/).

Comment: Thanks @Udo E! But this is called when "window" is load,no? I need to execute the "print", when "mywindow" is load. And this is created inside the method that you call.

Comment: @Abraham, see my update. use it and see if it works.

Comment: Hi Udo! It works. It generates the new window with the correct content, but always generate a infinite loop and dont print. What am I doing wrong? Sorry for ask too much, but I really dont know why it happens.

Comment: Hi again! It works, I deleted for an error  mywindow.document.close(); for this I recieved a loop.

Comment: @Abraham, glad to know it works. Are you using `$(mywindow).onload();`? If you are, put only code accessing `mywindow` inside this handler. Yes, I see you have `mywindow.document.close()` and `mywindow.close()`. I didn't notice that earlier. I have updated the answer. Hope the problem is resolved now.

Answer (score 0):

You can call printpage() function if the entire page has loaded.

`$(window).bind("load", function() {
   // code here
});`

Comment: It seems he is not using jQuery

Comment: Dont care about it, I'm starting to using jquery in class, I can try it. @Masud if is use: ```$(mywindow).bind("load", function() {
   mywindow.print()
}); ``` it should work?

Comment: @Masud I tried this code and this always generate the page in a new link. But mywindow.print() dont work. I refer, that this dont generate the PDF and loop loading

Comment: @Abraham you can try this one `window.onload = function() { mywindow.print(); }`

Comment: Hi @Masud ! shouldn't I add mywindow.close?

Comment: I tried it , and generates correctly the page. But dont shows the option to print it. This only show the generated page, and generate an infinite loop. What am I doing wrong? :)