# window.addEventListener ('load' function()) not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page with many articles, now on clicking an article I need to open a new window(compare.html) and show its specifications.
I have constructed  an array for my html to render and it works fine if its shown in same page but on new window for the html to render I used window.addEventListener("load", function())

Here is the code I used:-

```
rendered  = compareTpl(articleObj); // this contains the html block,

var w = window.open("compare.html", "compare",
                    "width=960, height=800, scrollbars=yes");

w.addEventListener("load", function()
{
  w.document.getElementById("mdpo").innerHTML = rendered;
 // I am placing my html inside the div(mdpo) content of compare.html page
});
```

It works fine for single article click but on next click the page goes blank.

Please help me with this

Comment: Any errors in browser console?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3030859/detecting-the-onload-event-of-a-window-opened-with-window-open could this be helping?

Comment: @Reporter no errors in console