# Properly message communication cross-origin with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, async-await, cross-domain, postmessage

#### Background

I'm trying to write a greasymonkey script that allow `site-A` (Google for example in this discussion) to get and process result from `site-B` (yandex for example in this discussion)

The final form looks like this (hopefully):

```
// script on google.com
async function test1(){
    let targetURL = "https://yandex.com/";
    let pWin = window.open(targetURL);
    let result = await GetAnswer(pWin, "what is A");
    alert(result) // "A is not B"
  
    function GetAnswer(win, question){
      // get search result by postMessage
    }        
}
```

### The problem

Forget about the async/await part for now, I have problem communicating with `postMessage` already...

If I post message immediately, `site-B` got nothing, the message sent before it's ready

```
let pWin = window.open(targetURL);
pWin.postMessage("search 'what is A'", targetURL);
```

If I try to post in `onload` event, this won't work because `onload` event is not accessible for cross-origin `pWin`

```
let pWin = window.open(targetURL);
pWin.onload=()=>{
  pWin.postMessage("search 'what is A'", targetURL);
}
```

I found [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12659656/1328043), but can't really understand what it says...

I'm quiet new to `postMessage` (the first time using it tbh), is there example or demo to learn how to communicate between cross-origin site (that not owned by me)?

Comment: since site-A is loading site-B, i.e. site-A is loaded, site-B isn't, yet, then you *initiate* the "communication" from site-B, in code that is in site-B

Comment: Ho, that's a new route I didn't noticed, I'll have a try

Answer (score 0):

I managed to written a working demo inspired by @Jaromanda X's idea, but warping event listener in a promise looks weird, I'm not sure I'm doing the right thing. Any suggestion is welcomed

The following use Google as `site-A`, Baidu as `site-B`

Scripts in google (`site-A`)

```
  let q = "question to ask";
  let result = await GetBaiduResult(q);
  // get result from q, all details are hidden
  alert(result);

  // Sets up a new MessageChannel
  // so we can return a Promise
  async function GetBaiduResult(query) {
    // For security
    let targetOrigin = "https://www.baidu.com";
    // Open search child window
    let pWin = window.open(targetOrigin + "/s?wd=" + encodeURIComponent(query));

    // wait for opened ready, TODO: add timeout
    await new Promise(res=>{
      window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false);
      async function receiveMessage(event)
      {
        // open ready message from target origin
        if (event.origin === targetOrigin && event.data === 'openedReady') {
          res();
        }
      }
    })

    return new Promise(res => {
      const channel = new MessageChannel();
      // this will fire when iframe will answer
      channel.port1.onmessage = e => res(e.data);

      // let target know we're expecting an answer
      // send it its own port
      pWin.postMessage(query, targetOrigin, [channel.port2]);
    });
  }
```

Scripts in Baidu(`site-B`)

```
  let targetOrigin = "https://www.google.com"
  window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false);

  // tell papa we're ready
  if(window.opener){
    window.opener.postMessage('openedReady', targetOrigin);
  }

  // load event
  async function receiveMessage(event)
  {
    if (event.origin !== targetOrigin) {
      return;
    }
    let result = await GetSearchResult(event.data);
    event.ports[0].postMessage(result);
  }

  // work
  async function GetSearchResult(query){
    let result = "answer" //TODO: get actual result
    return result;
  }
```