# Javascript CallBack

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp, callback

I have a JavaScript function "print_something", which is implemented in around 300 jsp help pages.
I turned out this "print_something" function has to be corrected.
So I am searching for a solution not to change 300 files.

I have one page where I open custom help page:

```
window.open('SomeHelpPage101.htm', 'Help', 'location=no,status=no,height=500,width=600,resizable,scrollbars');
```

I tryed to redefine function like this:

```
var jsObject = window.open('SomeHelpPage101.htm', 'Help', 'location=no,status=no,height=500,width=600,resizable,scrollbars'); 
jsObject.print_something() = function(){//corrected function}
```

It all works well in Firebug if I do step by step. But if I run the code it happens that window.open(...) is not yet finished because it is asynchronous so my redefine doesn't work.

How can I force window.open(...) to finish first and afterwards redefining print_something() would be sucessful.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: `jsObject.print_something() =` does not seem to be right. [According to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.open), `window.open` will *always* return a reference to the new window if everything worked well.

Comment: Rather than putting the same js function in 300 files, you should move that to a standalone `.js` file and then simply include that file on 300 pages.

Comment: I don't know if you can do that, but if you can it would be `jsObject.print_something = function () {}`.  The `jsObject.print_something()` you have is a method call.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself. Copypasting same code multiple times == Maintenance trouble.

Answer (score 0):

I think this has already been covered so here is a link to it:

[Set a callback function to a new window in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2797560/set-a-callback-function-to-a-new-window-in-javascript)

Comment: I tryed like this:

    var RunCallbackFunction = function() { }; //reference holder only
    
    function custom_print() { 
        alert('parent function!'); 
        self.focus(); 
        self.print();  
    } 
    
    var helpPopup = window.open(CustomPage101.htm'); 
    helpPopup.onload = function() { helpPopup.RunCallbackFunction = custom_print; };

But when I try to print parent function is still not allerted.
Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: seems you missing a ' in   var helpPopup = window.open(CustomPage101.htm')
 do some kind check like (window.onload != null) first so you don't overwrite it. I never tried this, but maybe save the reference in a variable first, then use a wrapper function contain old onload and your callback function instead.

Comment: I also tryied:

    var helpPopup =  window.open(CustomPage101.htm');
    helpPopup.onload = function() {
        helpPopup.custom_print = function() {
        alert('parent function!'); 
        helpPopup.focus(); 
        helpPopup.print(); 
    };
 
But still not sucess...

Comment: check if helpPopup.custom_print was called before document ready. also fix that ' in your code. Also, what you want overwrite is the print function isn't it? or is that the custom_print is what you want to overwrite?

Comment: Yes custom_print is the function implemented in all pages I want to redefine.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys very much for help and advices. :)

The solution was with setInterval function where we wait and check if object is initialised.

```
function Help() 
{
   // asynchronous object initialisation with "window.open"
   var jsOBJ = window.open('HelpPage' + pageID + '.htm', 'Help', 'location=no,status=no,height=500,width=600,resizable,scrollbars'); 
   // check every 100 ms if "window.open" has finished and "jsOBJ.custom_print" has initialised
   var helpTimer = setInterval(function() { 

       if(jsOBJ.custom_print) { 
           clearInterval(helpTimer); 
           // override function which is declared in child pages which we open with "window.open"
           jsOBJ.custom_print = function() { 
              alert('Test call from redefined parent function.'); 
              jsOBJ.print(); 
           }; 
       } 
   }, 100);   
}
```