# Callback function call when child window is close

Tags: javascript

I have open child window when click on button.In this window I have save some data into database.
I want to call another java script function when child window is close.

I have already tried this [Set a callback function to a new window in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2797560/set-a-callback-function-to-a-new-window-in-javascript) solution but it is not working.

So please tell me how to call callback function ?

I have also set one hidden field from child window after successfully save.I have try to alert this hidden value but its alert before updating.

```
function open_child()
{
    $("#child_succ").val(0);
    alert($("#child_succ").val());
    window.open("child.php","Ratting","width=550,height=300,left=150,top=200,toolbar=1,status=1");
    alert($("child_succ").val());
}
```

**Callback function**

```
function test()
{
    alert("called from child window");
}
```

Comment: you need to trap the onbeforeunload event, which is not 100% reliable.

Comment: @MarcB Any other way to call function after close child window or call function of parent window from child window?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You may call a parent function from child window this way:

```
window.opener.your_function()
```

To call a child function in parent window:

```
var w = window.open(somelocation,''); //has a function on `window` called "test"
w.test();
```

If any of this tips help you, you may show us how the callback approach was used by you.

Hope this helps you.

Regards!

Answer (score -1):

In the example you gave us the function is called on load event, so you have to change it with on close event:

```
// This function is defined in the child window
var RunCallbackFunction = function() { }; //reference holder only


// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------


// This code should appear in the parent window
//random function you want to call

function myFunc() { alert("I'm a function in the parent window"); }

//to actually open the window..
var win = window.open("window.html");
win.onclose = function() { win.RunCallbackFunction = myFunc; };
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclose' of undefined