# HTML _blank with javascript link opens empty tab

Tags: javascript, html

clicking on this link opens new empty tab, without any url. When I remove the _blank attribute, in the same tab, correct url opens. How this should be done then ?

Thanx a lot

```
<a  target="_blank" href="javascript:parent.func('/InternalPath/MorePath')" class="someclass">Goal</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

why not modify `parent.func()` to open link on new tab by itself? add some `window.open(url)`

It *may* be quite easy.

Else, you could try to use some callback function

```
var RunCallbackFunction = function() { }; //reference holder only
```

Then in your parent (opener), set that function when that child window loads, like this:

```
//random function you want to call
function myFunc() { alert("I'm a function in the parent window"); }

//to actually open the window..
var win = window.open("window.html");
win.onload = function() { win.RunCallbackFunction = myFunc; };
```

This assigns the function in your parent to now be the target of that child...and you can point each child to a different function if you wish, they're all independent.

based on [Set a callback function to a new window in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2797560/set-a-callback-function-to-a-new-window-in-javascript)

Comment: i would like not to change this function, it is used on many places, and not each time i need a new tab. Sometimes I want URL to open in same tab. But, im not sure I understand, why this can not work like this, from html ?

Comment: Trying to throw some light to it... Suppose you have a function that changes the text in a textbox in the same page the function is. Javascript doesn't allow you to open that call in a new window because of THE CONTEXT: there is no textbox in the new page(yet), so how could you reference it? Else, could you share some more code to try to help better?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding what you're looking for you wish to open the link in a new tab, rather than opening a blank page in a new tab (apologies for not asking this as a comment, I can't comment yet).

If so, try this:

```
<a  target="_new" href="javascript:parent.func('/InternalPath/MorePath')" class="someclass">Goal</a>
```

Comment: _blank opens new tab. tab does open, but URL is not there. Tab is empty

Comment: Right, so wouldn't target="_new" work for you? It's working for me.

Comment: Shihan, the tab does open, but the URL is not there. Tab has empty url. With _new is the same

Comment: Yeah, I just did some more research, it's the javascript: part that prevents it.

Comment: can you be so kind and send me the links to the research ? maybe it says how to handle it ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4964130/target-blank-vs-target-new
shows that my answer is wrong. It works, but only because of browser support. The rest of my research was simply testing it myself. I haven't gotten it to work. If I do I'll update my answer.