# listen even of JavaScript when child popup onload for external link

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup, onload

I want to know that is child popup completely lorded or not?

When i use internal pages of domain like test.html it working but when i am trying with external domain as in my code it not working . so is the any way to achieve this with JavaScript or Jquery.

I am writing code as following.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var popup;
   function test() 
   {
        popup = window.open("http://dailyhoroscope.com/", "Popup", "width=300,height=100");
        popup.onload = function()
        {
              // Do Somthing 
        }
   };        
</script>
```

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2797574

Comment: It is not duplicated question. Your given question is for same internal domain and i want to work with external domain.

Comment: Not possible to add an onload on a window with content not having same origin. In ALL cases add the onload handler BEFORE changing location/src

Comment: Not even `var w=window.open("","newwin");
w.document.write('<body onload="alert(\'loaded\')"><iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="http://dailyhoroscope.com/"></iframe></body>');
w.document.close();`

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have this onload declaration on the body, add it (or any event which you are trying to create a window with)